# Unable to mount root filesystem in LFS

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, uefi, lfs

Lately, I've been building an [LFS [Linux From Scratch]](https://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable) system for my [Raspberry Pi Single Board Computer](https://raspberrypi.org), and I'm currently on the very last step. I'm attempting to compile [Linux 5.19.2 from the official kernel.org repository](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.19.2.tar.xz), but every time I install the kernel and reboot, the following happens:

1. Rainbow splash screen appears [READING FAT32 PARTITION]
2. Raspberry Pi Logo appears [UEFI FIRMWARE LOADED]
3. GRUB2 Boot menu appears
4. This kernel panic appears:
   [image: LFS linux kernel panic text]

And that's it. The boot process stops and remains stuck there forever. The most likely problem I can think of is that a certain filesystem is not enabled in my kernel configuration. Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Link to `/boot/config-5.19.2`: [/boot/config-5.19.2](https://pastebin.com/ZKWBEVSD)

**UPDATE**
I generated an initramfs using the guidance on [this BLFS page](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable/postlfs/initramfs.html), and when I rebooted, I was greeted with what I initially thought was a wonderful surprise - an initramfs shell. I now get this:

```
The device /dev/sda2, which is supposed to contain the
root file system, does not exist.
Please fix this problem and exit this shell.

Encountered a problem!

Dropping you to a shell.

sh: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Innapropriate ioctl for device
sh: no job control in this shell
sh-5.1# _
```

I was hoping I could debug my system from there, but for some reason it won't let me type. So I decided to add `ls -a /dev` to my initramfs init script so I could see what devices my kernel was detecting. However, the results were quite disturbing:

```
.       core            full  mem   ptmx   snapshot tty   tty11 tty15 tty19 tty22 tty26 tty3  tty33 tty37 tty40 tty44 tty48 tty51 tty55 tty59 tty62 tty9    ttyS2   vcs1  vcsu1
..      cpu_dma_latency input null  random stderr   tty0  tty12 tty16 tty19 tty23 tty27 tty30 tty34 tty38 tty41 tty45 tty49 tty52 tty56 tty6  tty63 ttyAMA0 ttyS3   vcsa  vga_arbiter
char    fb0             kmsg  port  rtc    stdin    tty1  tty13 tty17 tty20 tty24 tty28 tty31 tty35 tty39 tty42 tty46 tty5  tty53 tty57 tty60 tty7  ttyS0   urandom vcsa1 zero
console fd              kvm   psaux rtc0   stdout   tty10 tty14 tty18 tty21 tty25 tty29 tty32 tty36 tty4  tty43 tty47 tty50 tty54 tty58 tty61 tty8  ttyS1   vcs     vcsu
```

There are no files that start with `sd` or `mmcblk`! Now I am confident that there is definitely something wrong with my kernel configuration that is preventing it from detecting physical devices.

**UPDATE** - Updated kernel version to linux 6.0.5 and recompiled my initramfs but there is no difference.

**UPDATE** - I realized that Raspberry Pi OS didn't use UEFI variables, so I thought that compiling GRUB with a UEFI variable supporting system would solve my problem. So I somehow installed Debian GNU/Linux 11 for arm64 on my Raspberry Pi and found that UEFI variables were supported [by running `efivar -l`]. I recompiled GRUB with UEFI variable support, but this did not solve my issue either.

**UPDATE** - It would seem as if the problem is NOT with my kernel compilation, because even when I copied and pasted my Debian installation [for arm64]'s kernel configuration file and recompiled my kernel, it still gave me the same result. It would seem as if there is some package that I have not installed to detect physical devices.

**UPDATE** - I actually figured out a crude way to get my system to boot, but this does not solve my problem. I got it to boot my entering the GRUB command line on my Debian installation and entering the following commands:

```
grub> linux (hd0,1)/vmlinuz-5.10.0-19-arm64 root=/dev/sdb2 rootfstype=ext4 init=/bin/bash
grub> initrd (hd0,1)/initrd.img-5.10.0-19-arm64
grub> boot
```

I don't want to always use an external installation to boot my system, and neither does this help me find the problem. If I compiled my LFS kernel with my Debian installation's kernel config file, shouldn't the kernel do the same thing? I also accidentally made another discovery: If I try to boot my Debian installation without loading the initramfs, I get a kernel panic *almost exactly* like the one shown above. What role does the initramfs play in locating partitions? I am now even more confused than I was before.

Comment: 1) your kernel doesn't see partitions 2) it obviously cannot mount one of them. Looks like you've not compiled something in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my kernel was installing kernel modules to `/boot/modules/` instead of `/usr/lib/modules/` I simply copied-and-pasted `/boot/modules` into `/usr/lib/modules` to fix my issue.